# What's an SS contact?

Tags: developing, processing

In this place I might go this afternoon to have my film developed, they quote a price for Processing + SS contact. What is this? I looked everywhere online couldn't find an answer. 
Thx!

Comment: By the way, I know what a contact is. Its the SS part that I've no idea about...

Comment: You could always call and ask them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is "single sheet", but asking *them* is the sure way to know what they mean. Doesn't ring a bell as a commonly used acronym in regard to (contact) prints.